# Onclick should create link and open it as well

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, concatenation

I am new to JavaScript and html. I am trying to create a link using two input boxes and create a link so I can further fetch data from it's API. I tried every method but it is not happening.
I am using this code.

```js
function openlink() {
  var a = document.getElementById("p1").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("p2").value;

  location.href = "http://" + a + b + "/webhdfs/v1/?user.name=hduser1&op=LISTSTATUS";
}
```

```html
p1: <input type="text" id="p1" value="fvalue"> P2: <input type="text" id="p2" value="svalue">

<p>Click On button.</p>

p3: <input type="button" id="p3" onclick="function openlink()">
```

Also, I am facing error of

> "unexpected end of input " at the end of P3 line

can anyone help??

Comment: Change onclick= "openlink()"

Comment: `Java` !== `JavaScript`

Comment: Remove `function` in `onclick` , just `onclick="openlink()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mentioned function inside onclick which gave error.

**`p3: <input type="button" id="p3" onclick= "openlink()">`**
Try this

```html
<html>
<body> 
   p1: <input type="text" id="p1" value="fvalue" >
   P2: <input type="text" id="p2" value="svalue">

   <p>Click On button.</p>

   p3: <input type="button" id="p3" onclick= "openlink()">

<script>
     function openlink () {
     var a = document.getElementById("p1").value ;
     var b = document.getElementById("p2").value ;

     location.href = "http://" + a + b + "/webhdfs/v1/?user.name=hduser1&op=LISTSTATUS" ;
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the function in onclick without the keyword function

```js
function openlink () {
     var a = document.getElementById("p1").value ;
     var b = document.getElementById("p2").value ;

     location.href = "http://" + a + b + "/webhdfs/v1/?user.name=hduser1&op=LISTSTATUS" ;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body> 
   p1: <input type="text" id="p1" value="fvalue" >
   P2: <input type="text" id="p2" value="svalue">

   <p>Click On button.</p>

   p3: <input type="button" id="p3" onclick= "openlink()" value="Click Me">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call a function which is declared, you dont need to use function keyword. Just write onclick="openlink()". Only in cases where you want to execute inline javascript, you can write JS code directly instead of writing function. For example onclick="location.href='http://someURL?user.name=a&op=b'". Hope this helps.

Comment: My url is not fixed ,it keeps on changing

Comment: Oh, okay. In that case, write the function openLink and form the url like you were doing. Inline JS is only if your URL is fixed or if the JS code is like 1 line of code.

Comment: @ParthPatankar - Did it work for you? any issue you're seeing in generating the link?

Answer (score 0):

remove the keyword function from `onclick=""`

Use `onclick="openlink()"`  instead of `onclick="function openlink()"`

Comment: Still not creating a link